# Android application deployment

Tags: android, deployment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install the application on real device without publishing and Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084745/how-to-install-the-application-on-real-device-without-publishing-and-eclipse)

Besides the Android Marketplace, what are my options as far as deploying an Android application to someone remotely?

The particular issues I am up against are that I have an application which I have written which addresses a somewhat limited problem, for my sister. She is mostly computer literate, but not a developer and lives hours away.

I could see this same issue being common if a company were to want to develop an application for their shiny new G1s and then deploying their application. Surely there is a non-developer-centric way to do this.