# How to install an Android application on a real device without publishing and Eclipse?

Tags: android, deployment

How can I install an application without any developer tools (Eclipse, Android SDK tools)?

I've compiled and created an .apk file. Now I am gonna send this apk file to my friend.

He is not an Android developer; he doesn't know how to use Eclipse or the SDK.
And I don't want to publish my application to android market.

Is there a way to launch the application on a real device without publishing it or having access to a machine with the SDK?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can deploy the .apk file on your local server(apache or jboss) with a static IP to make the file available for download. Now just open the download link of the apk file in your mobile browser. The device will automatically start the installation after the download completes.

Comment: As far as I recall, installation doesn't start automatically; you have to select the APK from the downloads list.  Or perhaps it varies by device (or browser implementation).

Comment: As dtmilano said, you also have to go to Settings -> Application -> Unknown sources to allow installation from non-Market before it allows you to install the application. Otherwise it won't allow you to install.

Answer (score 13):

The way I usually do this is:

1. Plug in my USB cable to my PC and mount my SD card on my computer
2. Get the APK file somewhere on my SD card on the phone
3. Unmount the SD card on my PC, allowing the phone to see the SD card contents again
4. Use Astro File Manager or some similar app to browse to that file on the SD card and select it, which will prompt you if you want to install the app on your phone.

Answer (score 10):

You should set
*Settings -> Application -> Unknown sources*
to allow installation from non-Market.
Then, once your application is published somewhere, you can download it an install it.

Answer (score 7):

Also you can use 'adb install ' to install apk's to your device.

Though this approach requires you to have adb available on your computer and adb is part of the sdk.

Another, easier approach, is using DropBox. This enables you to save the apk in the dropbox/public folder, create a URI from there and supply this to your friend. Then have him download the apk. Android will notify him when it's done, so he only has to click the notification and Android will ask him whether or not he wants to install this software.

Comment: this looks like the easiest way, IMO.

Answer (score 5):

Try [DeployGate](https://deploygate.com). With the service you can generate a download page like this:

https://dply.me/7hmric

Then it will guide your friends to install your app and you can see how is going, *e.g.* which version is installed or updated, or app is crashed, in realtime.

Though it's a very common question, there were no simple way to achieve it. Even if we can send people an APK file through whatever, they have to change the "Unknown Sources" setting before the installation. We have to take care of this kind stuff everyday. It's simply a waste of time. So we made DeployGate, a tester-friendly private app distribution service to help the developers just like you. :)

Disclaimer: I'm a developer of the service.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully you will find the answer from here [Install Android application on Android Device](http://javasrilankansupport.blogspot.com/2012/06/install-android-application-on-android.html)

Add your APK file to your device SD card and run it, you must allow to install non-market application on your device before you going to install.

Go to **Setting -> Application Setting  ->Unknown Source** and tick check box which will allow to install non-market application on your device

Answer (score 0):

what i usually do is:
1. Through mail: i send the .apk to their mail id.
2. do open his mail in his mobile. and download the attached .apk.
3. it will ask for installation and do run.

Answer (score 0):

If doing from a windows based server with IIS 7.

Setup a website, with a page named default.asp

Add this line to the asp page;

Setup a mime with extension '.apk' and MIME type 'application/vnd.android.package-archive'

When you connect to the page http://yourUrl.co.uk, it will automatically start the download, and include it in the download manager so it can be selected from the drop down menu using default installer.

If the MIME isn't setup correctly then you will have to use a file explorer to open the apk with an installer.

Answer (score 0):

Step-1 : Run Application in AVD First, then Close it.

Step-2 : See in bin/ folder contain AppNm.apk file.Just right click and copy it.

Step-3 : Now Connect Your Phone with Pc and Turn USB Storage on from your phone.

Step-4 : Now go to in your SD card Location and Paste it any location. just        remember that location.

Step-5 : Eject/Remove Your phone from pc and check your file in SD card

Step-6 : Now click on it and install....